# How to force click a span element on click of glyphicon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table cell which has 2 span elements in it:

```
<span contentEditable=true class="editspan"></span>
<span class="pencilspan glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right"></span>"
```

When I click on `span1` I get an input box which I can edit. I want to force a click on `span1` if I click on `span2` (edit glyphicon). How can I do this?

Comment: I tried using `$('.pencilspan').click(function() { $('.editspan').click(); }); inside $(document).ready(function(){}` at the top of my js file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, if you click span 2, then you want it to click on span 1 also?

```js
$('.pencilspan').click(function() {
  alert("pencilspan is clicked")
  $('.editspan').click();
  
  alert("editspan is automatic clicked")
});

$('.editspan').click(function() {
  $('<input placeholder="box created by editspan"/>').appendTo('body')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="editspan">span 1</span><br>
<span class="pencilspan glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right">span2</span><br>
```

This should give you an idea about it.

Updated with your spans, Only added some text inside for the visible effect

Comment: Editing question with exact spans I have and I tried using `$('.pencilspan').click(function() {
  $('.editspan').click();
});` inside `$(document).ready(function()` at the top of my js file but it did not work.